# Generator comprehension Vs Array comprehension

Tags: javascript

In javascript,

How do I understand the difference in usage of

`myList = (for (i of [ 1, 2, 3 ]) i*i );`

and

`myList = [for (i of [ 1, 2, 3 ]) i*i ];`

?

How does working of *Generator comprehension* different from *Array comprehension*?

When to use what?

Comment: Generator is lazy, array isn't. I suppose that's the difference. Look into Python list comprehensions for example.

Comment: @elclanrs array comprehensions give array type object as output, what about generator comprehensions?

Comment: I guess they give "generators", so basically the entities which you can use along with `for (i of gen()) { ... }` syntax.

Comment: @apendua Can I say `my_list = (1, 2, 3, 4);`?

Answer (score 2):

According to MDN, [Generator Comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Generator_comprehensions) (and [Array Comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions)) are a part of the EcmaScript 2016 standard, which is still in development. So you won't encounter them too often in the wild yet. Currently it is only implemented in Firefox.

**Generator (Comprehensions)**

The main difference is that a *generator comprehension* returns a Generator:

```
> myList = (for (i of [ 1, 2, 3 ]) i*i );
> Generator {  }
```

Which is (also) an iterator with a `.next()` method:

```
> myList.next();
> Object { value: 1, done: false }
```

So a generator can be useful *if you need to get the data sequentially* (such as in a `for-of` loop) or if you want to pass data back in to the generator to change the result of the following yields (eg. `myList.next(2);`).

[Kyle Simpson provides a good introduction to generators](http://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators).

**Array Comprehensions**

An *array comprehension* on the other hand returns an Array directly:

```
> myList = [for (i of [ 1, 2, 3 ]) i*i ];
> Array [ 1, 4, 9 ]
```

You could get the same result with an Generator Comprehension as well using the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...`:

```
> myList = [...(for (i of [ 1, 2, 3 ]) i*i )];
> Array [ 1, 4, 9 ]
```